# How to run one of failed tests in new tab in PyCharm?

Tags: django, unit-testing, pycharm

Given situation:

1. There is an app with 2000+ tests, all tests execution takes about 15-20 min.
2. After major changes, a lot of tests are failing (let's say, 100+ tests). Re-execution of failed tests is possible by pressing corresponding button in Run window and takes about 2 min.
3. Within the failed tests, only 2-3 tests re-execution is needed to identify and fix the issues in few iterations 'change code - run tests - check results'.

... but, currently the only option I have is to rerun all 100+ of failed tests, which is a big waste of time.

Is there possibility to re-run specific failed test in new Run window, keeping the list of the 100+ failed tests for later re-run?

I'm using current version of PyCharm, 2017.1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue was urgent, so I've done my best looking for a workaround and found something:

1. After all tests execution and failed tests rerun I can press 'Pin' button in Run window (it will keep all failed tests list).
2. Now any test from the list can be re-run ('Run' option in test's context menu), it will be done in new tab!